# How to compare web service date to calendar date in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, calendar

My web service response comes in this format: `19/2/2011`. I want to compare this web service date to my own calendar date.

Is there any answer and how to highlight that date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
             parseData();
        }
    });
t.start();

Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Split strings here and check them 
        }
    });
t1.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have both the date in strings you can break it up into day, time , year token and then can compare the strings....this will be a easy and raw approach to do this

Comment: i have done this,but when i run first time it gives me null,after 2, 3 times it gives me the value.how

Comment: you must be doing this check before your data get fetched from the service....
What you do maintain 2 threads one for fetching the data and other joining the first and then spliting the string and checking..
 
Check the code i posted to do this

Comment: i m getting the date from the webservice in splitted formate but unable to compare with the calender date

Comment: do you have calander date in Strings?
if yes then simply call the equals method to compare...
Or even you can parse it to int then compare..its up to you